# Do any temples allow donations via e-Hundis?

Tags: temple, practice

People like to go cashless nowadays, so, do any temples have e-Hundis to accept donations either through card or Paytm (a payment gateway) in temples?

<strike>Is it permitted in our scriptures? Have any acharyas commented on it?</strike>

Comment: Kindly Read your question again and think, our scriptures were written long back like in ancient time when digital technology was not in existence. How come you except scripture would write something about it ? Now does it make any sense to Even ask this question ?

Comment: Don't compare humans artifical inventions with scriptures.  Paytym cards are humans find not with respect to divinity. So this question doesn't fit to standard of the site! Kindly analyse before asking these type of questions.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto if they knew about so many astras which some compare to be greater than atomic bombs, then it is not out of possibility.

Comment: This question is very much about Hinduism as e-religion is going to become a significant part of Hinduism,

Comment: @SK yeah, people were so quick to rush and close it as off topic

Comment: @MohMur Scriptures lay emphasis on charity, how is it done should be common sense, for instance people also do gupt daan, not necessary to have a slab in the temple with your name embedded on it. Motive is to donate not how, for such things Lord has given us intellect.

Comment: This is something temple managements will think and decide after a meeting with an agenda. This decision changes from temple to temple. We are none to say if it's allowed or not.Hence, it is out of scope of site. Scriptures are eternal but they don't talk about paytm, paypal etc., eternal has other meaning.

Comment: I dont understand why this question is put as off-topic.

Comment: @MohMur yes, e-hundi is allowed. Tirumala Tirupathi Devasthanam (TTD) allows e-hundi for Sri Venkateswara temple at Tirumala. I have contributed thru e-hundi. It is very convenient and safe, compared to carrying cash in the busy queue lines.

Comment: @Lazy Lubber please vote to re-open if you disagree with the closure of this question.

Comment: @SK I am new. How do I vote to re-open?

Comment: @SK Sorry, I dont see any option to re-open. But I think the question is valid and I answered it in the comments section.

Comment: @MohMur I've made some edits so your question can be re-opened. You can revert if you want to keep the original (which I think is off-topic).

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria do we get real moksha or e-moksha after all that?

Comment: @sv. I don't think OP is asking if any temples allow cashless transactions. He is asking if it is allowed according to scriptures or acharyas. What is the meaning of strikeoff? Does it mean the line is present or not?

Comment: 'What is the meaning of strikeoff?' - that he's no longer interested in that question. 'I don't think OP is asking if any temples allow cashless transactions' - yes, let's see if he's ok with the modified question. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @sv. But how do you know if he is no longer interested in that question? He actually edited that it is on-topic and acharyas and scriptures being eternal and wants scriptural or something of that sort. If he is no longer interested, why not remove? Let's not put our words into others mouths. Why edit with what we want? First their intent should be known and then edited and not the other way.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma 'Why edit with what we want?' - because the question is useful to the community?

Answer (score 1):

If whatever is not prohibited is allowed, then it is allowed.  Since scriptures couldn't have known about electronic funds transfer, it is not prohibited.

In fact it is routine now to do pujas, samskaras etc. through teleconferencing.